# Visual studio Redistributable package x64 is needed to execute 64 bit application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

Consider a machine(64bit) is not having visual studio 2008 and redistributable package x64,
1. To run 64bit application(built by visual studio 2008 sp1) on that machine, do we need Redistributable package on that ?

Consider a machine(64bit) is having visual studio 2008 but it is not having redistributable package x64,
2. To run 64bit application(built by visual studio 2008 sp1) on that machine, do we need Redistributable package on that ?

what is the relation between redistibutable package x64 and 64 bit applications ?

Answer (score 2):

First off, this requirement exists for both 32-bit and 64-bit code.  You're just a bit more likely to be lucky with 32-bit code and somebody else having it installed before you.  As it was on your dev machine by the VS installer.

It is induced by a compiler setting.  Project + Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library setting.  All the project templates in VS have this setting at /MD.  You can change it to /MT and no longer have a dependency on the runtime DLLs, like msvcr90.dll.  The runtime library code will be linked into your program instead of relying on the DLLs to be present on the target machine.

You have to be careful however, the /MD setting is the safe setting.  It ensures that you won't get into trouble when you create your own DLLs and write code that returns C++ objects (like std::string) or pointers that must be released by the caller.  This won't work well if the DLL and the EXE each have their own copy of the CRT linked into them.  They will use different heaps, releasing a pointer across heaps cannot work properly.  A silent leak on XP, a crash on Vista and up.

The redistributable .exe is actually meant as a downloadable installer that your customer can use when you forget to write an installer for your program.  The much better solution is for you to write an installer that gets everything copied and installed properly.  It takes less than a minute to make one.  Add a Setup and Deployment + Setup project to your solution.  Right-click it, Add, Project Output.  Project + Properties, Prerequisites and tick the "Visual C++ Runtime Libraries (x64)" checkbox. If you prefer to create your own installer then you can use the merge modules in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules

Oh, and deploy the Release build, not the Debug build.  The debug version of the CRT is not distributable.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, you can link your programm statically against the C runtime library. In this case the redistributable package is not needed because all necessary functions are copied into your application's executable. If you however link against it dynamically, you should deliver the redistributable package with your application. While many other applications do this as well, there is no guarantee that the necessary runtime is available on the target system.

You can change how you link against the runtime in your project's settings dialog under "C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library".

The following MSDN article explains how you redistribute the necessary VC++ files: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=vs.80%29.aspx